# How to pick up html IDs from auto generated elements in Django formset using jQuery

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates

In some of my pages I am using Django inline formset. Where I am setting the `auto_id = True`, the element `id`s are generated quite conveniently.

In one case I need to pick up the auto generated id during runtime when the element gets `focus`.

I have tried a something like this:

```
$('#items td').on('focusin', function() {
        elemID = $(this).id;
});
```

But I am getting no result (`undefined`).

In the html codes the id is nicely lined up:

```
<input type="text" ......id="abc-1-xyz" class="......>
```

However for manually generated id tags, the above code works perfectly.

**Can somebody guide me as how I may get the element's id?**

## Edit:

Well, following is the html generated (reproducing *one segment* of it):

```
<td id="id_tIndx11" class="cls_tIndx11">
    <input type="hidden" name="catch_set-1-id" id="catch_set-1-id">
    <input type="hidden" name="catch_set-1-supp" id="catch_set-1-supp">
    <input type="text" name="catch_set-1-cntry" placeholder="type..." style="width:180px" id="catch_set-1-cntry" class="ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
</td>
```

`id_tIndx11` is the manually generated id.

I am trying to figure out how to get the id `id="catch_set-1-cntry"`.

Comment: put a console.log() in the on focuin and check if that function is triggering

Comment: Well if the table or div #items is being generated (I mean non-dom), I think you need to select it's parent wrapping container. $( "#parent-container" ).on( "click", "td", function() { ... Why not posting a fiddle where you append() that code the same way Django does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
$(document.body).on("focusin", 'input', function() {
      elemID = $(this).attr(‘id’);
      console.log(elemID);
});
```

Comment: **Edited** my query. The line suggested by you is not producing anything in the console. Pls check my edit. Even with `tr` index generated and using on the line suggested by you doesn't work (`undefined`), as was the situation earlier.

Comment: Put input in the target field. Chk my answer edited

Comment: The same result `undefined`.

Comment: Try putting only input

Comment: This time it is perfect. Good job!! Took some time to get back as I was trying to get the value picked up into another function. You certainly know your jQuery!!

Comment: Happy to help. BTW if you have too many inputs in the form/page this may be heavy on the browser. Give class name to the input you want to run the function and give the function target element as ‘input.classname’.